# python numpy add 1 element to empty matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have initialized matrix:

```
M = np.array(((),()))
```

M has the shape of (2,0) now. I wish to fill M by steps: firstly to add 1 number like

```
M[0] = np.append(M[0],55)
```

By this operation I want to get such a matrix

```
((55),())
```

How can I do this? I can make this with standard pythons arrays [] by "append" operation like

```
arr = [[],[]]
arr[0].append(55)
```

But after that, I need this array to be a numpy array and there is one extra type transform operation which I wish to avoid.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `ndarray`?  What `shape` and `dtype` are you aiming for?  What kinds of calculations are you going to do with this array?

Comment: The size of a `ndarray` is fixed.  You can reshape it, but the total number of elements has to remain unchanged.  To add elements you have to make a new array, and copy values.  If you do need to create an array incrementally, it's best to create lists (or lists of lists) and do one type conversion, or preallocate the array, and fill in values incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

The array you've written is no matrix because its axis has different dimensions.
You could do it like this

```
  import numpy as np
  x = np.zeros((2,1))
  x[0][0] = 55
```

Then if you want to append to it you can do something like:

```
x = np.append(x, [[42], [0]], axis=1)
```

Note that in order to append to a martrix all the dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Ok, it's clear, but how can I solve my problem if we don't call my "M" array by "matrix" but just an "array" with elements different by dimensions ?

Comment: Then use python arrays not numpy

Comment: sad( ok. Hope type transform isn't so costly

Comment: You can use numpy and input two lists like this `x = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
` numpy will transform it into an 1d array of list-objects. This is not the intended use of numpy though

Answer (score 1):

I can start with a 2 element object dtype array:

```
In [351]: M = np.array((None,None))
In [352]: M.shape
Out[352]: (2,)
In [353]: M
Out[353]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [354]: M[0]=(5,)
In [355]: M[1]=()
In [356]: M
Out[356]: array([(5,), ()], dtype=object)
In [357]: print(M)
[(5,) ()]
```

Or more directly (from a list of tuples) (beware, sometimes this produces a error rather than object array).

```
In [362]: np.array([(55,),()])
Out[362]: array([(55,), ()], dtype=object)
```

But I don't see what it's good for.  It would easier to construct a list of tuples:

```
In [359]: [(5,), ()]
Out[359]: [(5,), ()]
```

Do not try to use `np.append` like the list append.  It is just a clumsy front end to `np.concatenate`.

---

`M` as you create it is:

```
In [360]: M = np.array(((),()))
In [361]: M
Out[361]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

It can't hold any elements.  And you can't change the shape of the slots as you can with a list.  In `numpy` `shape` and `dtype` are significant.

You can specify `object` dtype:

```
In [367]: M = np.array([(),()], object)
In [368]: M
Out[368]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=object)
```

but it's still impossible to reference and change one of those 0 elements.